# Can a "select" get between the "delete" and "insert" of a "replace into" statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to know, if when I'm performing a "replace into" query, for example:

```
REPLACE INTO `table` (id, name) VALUES(1000, "table name")
```

and another "select" query is running at the same time, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE ID = 1000
```

could the mysql server execute it the following order?:

1. DELETE id=1000 FROM `table` (supposing the primary key exists already)
2. SELECT id=1000 FROM `table` -> no results
3. INSERT id=1000 INTO `table`

I know that "replace into" does delete and then insert (if primary/unique key already exists), but I want to know whether they are bound to execute one after the other, or if another query can be executed in between? Thanks.

Comment: This is not documented. In theory each statement is solid transaction. So if dirty reads allowed - maybe the situation is possible. Also take into account that "It is possible that in the case of a duplicate-key error, a storage engine may perform the REPLACE as an update rather than a delete plus insert, but the semantics are the same. There are no user-visible effects other than a possible difference in how the storage engine increments Handler_xxx status variables."

Comment: The only case I can see step #2 not seeing the row if you changed the isolation level to `READ UNCOMMITTED`; all other levels should always find the row. Anyway, maybe this case doesn't even happen at all. Read about Transaction Isolation Levels at See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html